# How to set row level lock in Informix?

Tags: sql, locking, informix

How to set row level lock in Informix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE customer(customer_num serial, lname char(20)...)
   LOCK MODE ROW;
```

Read more here: [Row and Key Locks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.perf.doc/perf227.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ALTER TABLE customer LOCK MODE(ROW);
```

(PAGE is the default)

More [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0083.htm).

If you want to find the current lock mode of a table:

```
SELECT tablename, lockmode FROM systables
```

Comment: To find the current lock mode of a table, the correct query is:   SELECT tabname, locklevel FROM systables

Answer (score 0):

Onstat with a hyphen argument

**onstat -**

[Onstat Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0495.htm)